# std::setlocale vs MB_CUR_MAX

Tags: c++, utf-8, c++17, locale

I work on Linux. In my C++ application I set locale this way:

```
std::setlocale(LC_ALL, "en_US.UTF-8");
```

After that `MB_CUR_MAX` equals `6`. Could you please explain why ? I have thought that after setting locale to `UTF-8` `MB_CUR_MAX` will be equal 4 because UTF-8 uses up to 4 bytes.

Answer (score 2):

Unicode codepoints use 32-bit unsigned integers. UTF-8 [was originally defined](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8#FSS-UTF) in such a way that it could encode all values within that range. However, UTF-16 was *not*; it could only ever encode a 21-bit range. So the Unicode standards committee decided that 21-bits were enough. Therefore, [UTF-8 at present](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3629) uses only 4 bytes instead of the 6 bytes it could use to cover the entire 32-bit range.

Perhaps your locale implementation is unaware of this and in some way supports the older version of UTF-8.